# Alert Condition Pine Script 5

Tags: pine-script, alert

I copies this script from Stackoverflow and made some minor adjustments to it.
My problem is that my Buy/Sell code does not work
My Script:
//@version=5

```
indicator('Prev Day Hi Lo Lines', overlay=true)

PDH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1])
PDL = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1])


var line l_pdh = na
var line l_pdl = na

if barstate.islast
    l_pdh := line.new(bar_index - 1, PDH, bar_index, PDH, extend=extend.both,           color=color.lime,width=3)
    l_pdl := line.new(bar_index - 1, PDL, bar_index, PDL, extend=extend.both,       color=color.red,width=3)
l_pdl

line.delete(l_pdh[1])
line.delete(l_pdl[1])

//===== BUY / SELL Condition 

Buy = close >= PDH
Sell = close <= PDL

var pos = 01

if Buy and pos <= 0
    pos := 1

if Sell and pos >= 0 
    pos := -1

Buysignal  = pos ==  1 and (pos !=  1)[1]
Sellsignal = pos == -1 and (pos != -1)[1]


Buylbl = label.new(bar_index, high, "Buy", yloc=yloc.belowbar, style=label.style_label_up)
Selllbl = label.new(bar_index, high, "Buy", yloc=yloc.belowbar, style=label.style_label_down)

Delete the old label
label.delete(Buylbl[1])    // Delete the old label
label.delete(Selllbl[1])
```

I want the script to generate a
"Buy" Signal when price crosses up the prev day high
and a
"Sell" Signal when the price crosses under prev day low

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will plot your lines and then generate the labels as you wish. Your code was close just a few errors. This will show the last signal for each, you can easily alter it to only show the last signal if you want.

```
indicator('Prev Day Hi Lo Lines', overlay=true)

PDH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1])
PDL = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1])

var line l_pdh = na
var line l_pdl = na

if barstate.islast
    l_pdh := line.new(bar_index - 1, PDH, bar_index, PDH, extend=extend.both,           color=color.lime,width=3)
    l_pdl := line.new(bar_index - 1, PDL, bar_index, PDL, extend=extend.both,       color=color.red,width=3)
    line.delete(l_pdh[1])
    line.delete(l_pdl[1])

//===== BUY / SELL Condition 

Buy = close >= PDH
Sell = close <= PDL

var pos = 01

if Buy and pos <= 0
    pos := 1

if Sell and pos >= 0 
    pos := -1

Buysignal  = pos ==  1 and (pos[1] !=  1)
Sellsignal = pos == -1 and (pos[1] != -1)

var label Buylbl = na
var label Selllbl = na

if Buysignal
    label.delete(Buylbl[1]) 
    Buylbl := label.new(bar_index, high, "Buy", yloc=yloc.belowbar, style=label.style_label_up)
if Sellsignal
    label.delete(Selllbl[1]) 
    Selllbl := label.new(bar_index, high, "Sell", yloc=yloc.belowbar, style=label.style_label_down)
```

Comment: Hi I try to give you a 1 rating but somehow it does not work